# How can I see other players choices in single draft?

Tags: dota-2

I just played a single draft game and mentioned my two favorite heroes and which one to pick. But one guy mentioned my 3rd hero that I could pick. So how do you see which heroes a team mate can pick in single draft mode?

Answer (score 3):

You can't.

Most likely you had scrolled past the hero, allowing it to be seen as a grayed pick choice.

Comment: You can scroll every hero and it will be seen in there hud afaik. So it was somekind of lucky guess?

Answer (score 0):

There's only 2 possible answers.

1. An absolutely lucky guess.
2. You accidentally scrolled through all your heroes without self-notice.

There's clearly **NO** other way he knows your 3 heroes in single draft.

Answer (score 0):

You can scroll through your heroes and they will be shown in grayed out fashion to your allies.

Furthermore you can suggest them below the cards on the right side. This is great in Single Draft because you can show all your 3 Heroes at once without typing anything.

Comment: too bad they removed that suggestion function in SD, i used to do that all the time...